# username and password are not set in cookie

Tags: php, html, mysql, cookies

i want to set username and password on check of remember me check box and destoy the cookie on uncheck of check box but when i click on remember me check box and check the output of cookie then there is no cookie set(no output). I want to show my code please check and tell me where i did the mistake:

```html
<div class="col-md-5">
 <h4>Login</h4>
 <form  method="post" action="" name="customer_form">   
  <?php 
   if($danger_msg_client){
   
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
     <strong><?php echo $danger_msg_client;?></strong>
    </div>
    <?php
   }
  ?>
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="client_username" id="client_username" placeholder="Email ID" required="required" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['username']; ?>"/>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="client_password" id="client_password" placeholder="Password" required="required" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['password']; ?>"/>
   </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <a href="client/forgot-password.php" class="pull-right"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i>&nbsp;Forgot Password</a>
  <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="client_remember" id="client_remember" class="btn btn-mini custom-checkbox active" value="1"
   <?php 
    if(isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {
     echo 'checked="checked"';
    }
    else {
     echo '';
    }
   ?> >
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remember Me
  </label>
  <input type="submit" name="customer_submit" id="customer_submit" value="LogIn" class="btn btn-success col-md-offset-5"/>
 </form>
</div>
```

```
session_start();    
print_R($_COOKIE);
include('inc/header.php');
//error_reporting(0);
include("agent_database.php");  
if (isset($_POST['customer_submit'])){  

    if ($_SESSION['email'] == $email_input && $_SESSION['password'] == $password_input){

        if(isset($_POST['client_remember']) == 1){

            echo "munesh";
            setcookie('username', $_POST['client_username'], time()+60*60*24*365);
            setcookie('password', $_POST['client_password'], time()+60*60*24*365);

        }else{

            echo "chaudhary";
            setcookie('username', $_POST['client_username'], false);
            setcookie('password', $_POST['client_password'], false);
        }               
        if($result_two > 0){

            $_SESSION['flag'] = true; 
            //echo '<script>location.href="client/dashboard/my-account.php"</script>';          
        }
    }
    $email_input = $_POST['client_username'];
    $client_remember = $_POST['client_remember'];
    $_SESSION['my_email'] = $_POST['client_username'];
    $_SESSION['my_password'] = $_POST['client_password'];
    $password_input = md5($_POST['client_password']); 
    $sql = "SELECT email, password, status FROM customer_regis WHERE email='".$email_input."' && password='".$password_input."' && status = 1 ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $result_two = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($row)."</br>";  
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
    else{

        $danger_msg_client = "please enter a correct email and password!";
    }

}
```

Comment: Password stored in a cookie?!? :( #fail

Comment: thanks for your reply but i want to show username and password in input field when user check the check box  that's why i want to store username and password in cookie.

Answer (score 3):

Password stored in cookies .. :/ :/ : /?????? 
Use session..

Comment: yes, i want. Because i need to show username and password in input field.

Comment: Check this, will help you http://www.downwithdesign.com/web-development-tutorials/adding-remember-feature-php-login-script/

Comment: `<?php
 print_R($_COOKIE);
 if (isset($_POST['customer_submit'])){ 
 
  if(isset($_POST['client_remember']) == 1){
  
   echo "munesh";
   setcookie('username', $_POST['client_username'], time()+60*60*24*365, 'http://rental.thedigitalmarketingonline.com/');
   setcookie('password', $_POST['client_password'], time()+60*60*24*365, 'http://rental.thedigitalmarketingonline.com/');
  
  }else{
   
   echo "chaudhary";
   setcookie('username', $_POST['client_username'], false);
   setcookie('password', $_POST['client_password'], false);
  }     
 }
 
?> `

Comment: same code is running on local host but this code is not working on live site i don't know why

Answer (score -1):

Check this URL.This might be useful.
http://www.bitrepository.com/php-autologin.html